# Making two windows stick to eachother without a delay

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window, position

I've created two windows with CreateWindowEx(), and now I'd like to stick them side-by-side, so that whenever one is moved, the other one moves relative to the other.

What's the right way of implementing this?

At the moment, I'm using this piece of code:

```
case WM_MOVING: // When the main window is being moved
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rWnd); // Get the current position of the main window
    MoveWindow(hwStats, rWnd.right - 1, rWnd.top, 140, 450, 1); // Move the other window relative to the main window
    return 1; // WM_MOVING is handled by the application
    break; // Done.
```

The problem with this, is that whenever I move the window, the other window is dragged a few pixels behind.
Now, it doesn't look *too* bad, but I'd really prefer if it looked a bit more solid.

Comment: Are you working in MDI Mode?

Comment: Maybe create you own application and attach 2 windows?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773003/attach-form-window-to-another-window-in-c-sharp

I've never tried it myself though

Comment: I don't quite see how that'd help me. (Or what that is for, for that matter.) - Here's an image to clarify what I want to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/WTkARUi.png , I'd like it so that when I move MainWindow, theOtherWindow would always stay at the side of the MainWindow, without a delay.

Comment: Google for 'Windows API docking'

Comment: `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` is the message you need to look for - when you're notified that one window is **about** to move, move the other one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem, I needed to change the `case` from `WM_MOVING` to `WM_MOVE`, and the function `MoveWindow() to` `SetWindowPos()`.

Thank you to Martin James, who told me about "Windows API Docking". That was very helpful.